# Using Visual Studio 2022 17.8.6 to build my UWP component, it should automatically generate the winmd file to package in nuget, it does not. Why?

Tags: uwp, nuget, visual-studio-2022, winmd

I have built a UWP component and now want to package it as a nuget to use in other applications. Visual Studio 2022 should "Produce reference winmd" file. It does not and there is no longer a checkbox to enable its generation. How is it done now in version 17.8.6 build of VS 2022?

I've researched online, and I have done a repo wide search of my disk directory. There were not results for the missing file.